# RTSP Media player crash

Tags: android, rtsp, rtp, rtcp

I am testing (`RTSP`/`RTP`/`RTCP`) streaming from my with HTC one X. After finishing the `RTSP` session I see `UDP` packets reaching ports and after few seconds, a fin `ack` from the mobile (in wireshark logs) for the `RTSP` port (`550` in my case). While debugging with logcat, I see following lines

```
I/ARTSPConnection(  144): status: RTSP/1.0 200 OK
I/MyHandler(  144): SETUP(1) completed with result 0 (Success)
W/MyHandler(  144): Missing 'source' field in Transport response. Using RTSP endpoint
I/ARTSPConnection(  144): status: RTSP/1.0 200 OK
D/MyHandler(  144): play
I/MyHandler(  144): PLAY completed with result 0 (Success) 
I/MyHandler(  144): Range: npt=0.000000-116.000000
I/MyHandler(  144): mNpt1=0.000000,mNpt2=116.000000
D/MyHandler(  144): streamInfo[1] = url=rtsp://10.23.202.70/A91_amr.3gp/trackID=2;seq=62846;rtptime=905384278
D/MyHandler(  144): mURL[0] : rtsp://10.23.202.70:550/A91_amr.3gp/trackID=2
D/MyHandler(  144): Before checking, trackIndex : 0, mTracks.size : 1
D/MyHandler(  144): string val : rtsp://10.23.202.70/A91_amr.3gp/trackID=2
D/MyHandler(  144): After checking, trackIndex : 1, mTracks.size : 1
F/MyHandler(  144): ./frameworks/base/media/libstagefright/rtsp/MyHandler.h:1592 CHECK_LT(     trackIndex,mTracks.size()) failed: 1 vs. 1
F/libc    (  144): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadbaad (code=1)
I/DEBUG   (  140): debuggerd: 1999-12-31 19:05:21
```

My server works fine with many other models. Has anyone faced a similar issue. I have been trying to get past this issue. Would be of great help if someone can point me the issue.

Comment: If you have the source code of MyHandler.h, suggest to add more log information to dig out what happened. Seems like the "trackIndex" changed.

Comment: I figured the issue. My PLAY response (200 OK) was missing the rtsp port. When i added the port the client started working. Funny thing is i do not know what track index has to do with this issue.Pantech,Lenovo and Samsung clients somehow do not crash and move to rtp part. Thanks for the suggestion.